# how do you link components between them on a protoboard

Tags: pcb, soldering, prototyping, board

I have the following protoboard (see picture below)

[image]

Each hole has a distance of 0.5mm

I want to link components between them. I found a few ways to do that:

1) Use tiny wires to connect the components

2) Solder the part of the board I'm using. However, issue is the dots between them are tiny (very actually) and my iron is kind of unfit for precision work.

Any insights would be great.

Cheers

Update:

Please find the size between holes of my protoboard and the the size of the tip of my iron (size in mm and cm)

[image]

Comment: For a beginner, the protoboard with copper stripes (all the way, or with a break after three holes) might be easier to use.

Comment: Thanks @WoutervanOoijen. My friend and I will have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pretty much got the answer. You can either make connections with wire or by creating solder bridges. It's also possible to use the extra lead length of through hole components to make connections.

Edit: given that your iron tip is a bit large and grungy looking, I would recommend buying a new tip. It doesn't need to be super tiny, maybe a 1/16" or something. By "extra lead length", I mean that it is possible to make connections by threading a component's leads through the board and then bending them to the place they need to connect to.

Comment: Hi @uint128_t what do you mean by extra lead length? And about the medium size tip iron , you can buy it anywhere in the retail, am I correct? Sorry my friend and I are not hugely familiar yet with soldering and dealing with protoboard. Cheers

Comment: What do you mean by the pitch?

Comment: @AndyK First let me clear somethings up. What is the distance between the holes on the protoboard? And what size is your iron tip currently?

Comment: please find the update of the size of the holes between the protoboard and the size of the iron tip on my update picture

Comment: Looks more like 2.54mm to me.

Comment: @AndyK I updated my answer with responses to your comments.

Comment: @uint128_t many thanks! My friend and I are very grateful for your answer! noobs in action! :)))

Comment: cheers @ignacio-vazquez-abrams :)))